# Health supplements/Vitamins bringing into Malaysia

Tags: customs-and-immigration, health, malaysia

Malaysian returning home after holiday in Australia, is there any restriction in bringing back health supplements & vitamins that we bought.

Answer (score 1):

Check the substances from which your health supplements and vitamins are made against this list before you travel http://www.customs.gov.my/en/tp/pages/tp_ie.aspx